# Add 'new folder' to right click menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How can you add a 'new folder' button to the windows explorer context menu?

Since this is my most often used 'new' item it would be great if it could be available without a double movement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various shell extensions around that accomplish this, e.g. FileMenuTools
http://www.lopesoft.com/en/fmtools/info.html

There's a trick, that you might find a little bit more handier: Ctrl+Shift+N can also be used in Windows 7 Explorer to create a new folder.

Comment: thanks andreas, can it be done via the registry? Also i know the hotkey but find i still work with the mouse first... habit?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a way to spawn the standard Windows Explorer way (the one used by SendTo or the New Folder-button/shortcut).